# Set caret to an initial child in a contenteditable div for cross-browser compatibility

Tags: javascript, contenteditable

I want to set caret to a child paragraph in my **contenteditable** div.

For cross-browser compatibility, I listen the first character input to the **contenteditable** div. If it is first, I insert to the div `<p> + first_char + </p>`

Following that, I try to *set caret* just after the first character in the paragraph.

It seems to work. But also an error occures at `sel.addRange` (see the code).

What is wrong, and how can I resolve it.

```js
$("#content-wrapper").on("keydown", ".contenteditable-div", function(event) {

  keyCodeNow = event.keyCode;
  
  if($(this).html() == ''){
    if((keyCodeNow > 47 && keyCodeNow < 58) || // number keys
       (keyCodeNow > 64 && keyCodeNow < 91)   || // letter keys
       (keyCodeNow > 95 && keyCodeNow < 112) // numpad keys
      ){
      $(this).html('<p>' + String.fromCharCode(keyCodeNow) + '</p>');

      var sel = window.getSelection();
      var range= sel.getRangeAt(0);

      var childNode = document.getSelection().anchorNode.firstChild.firstChild;

      console.log('Current position: '+range.startOffset+' inside '+range.startContainer); // Current position: 0 inside [object HTMLDivElement]
      range.setStart(childNode, 1);
      range.setEnd(childNode, 1);
      range.collapse(true);
      console.log('Next position: '+range.startOffset+' inside '+range.startContainer); // Next position: 1 inside [object Text]
      sel.removeAllRanges();
      sel.addRange(range); // Error: Discontiguous selection is not supported
      return false;
    }


  }
  ...
```